# Python functions returning another function

Tags: python, function

am not so much a pro in python but i came through this concept where you can create `a higher order function`. That is a function that returns another function. I have seriously read almost all answers here at StackOverflow but I seriously dont understand neither, might be am so dumb to understand, i dont want to presume that. But if someone would provide an intuitive guide into that, maybe provide an example, or a link to what someone might consider a better answer here at stack i'd appreciate.

This is the example am stuck at.

> For example, suppose you wanted to define linear(a,b) which returns a function f(x) that computes the value a*x+b. Using nested scopes:

**Provided this as the solution**

```
def linear(a, b):
    def result(x):
       return a*x + b
    return result
```

**And as a callable object**

```
class linear:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a, self.b = a,b
   def __call__(self, x):
      return self.a * x + self.b
```

Someone please make it clear for me.

Comment: I seriously doubt you have "read almost all answers here".

Comment: i bet you i have. About 20 solutions with no help. I can even link some

Comment: What's wrong with the stuff you posted?  If it's just a conceptual problem, what exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Maybe if you link to *ALL* of them, I'd be convinced.

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't fit in the comments...

Comment: A link maybe would help maybe!

Comment: What is the actual question? You want a guide written as an answer? This is too broad. You gotta be specific or write it yourself. A link is asking for off-site resources. Also strictly against the rules.

Comment: The problem with the snippet, How do you pass the argument x, how do you even get the final result

Comment: The argument `x` never gets passed into `linear`.  Instead, `linear` returns a function, which you then pass `x` to

Comment: look at how my guide call the function `taxes = linear(0.3, 2)`. Does this give you the final x

Comment: an example?, `taxes = linear(0.3, 2)`. Then call taxes?

Comment: No, it gives you a function, which uses `x` as a parameter.

Comment: Actually, the point i was missing is the `how to call the inner function` That's the last code in the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a small guide to help understand the first version:

```
def linear(a, b):
    def result(x):
       return a*x + b
    return result

ret = linear(2, 4)
print(ret)        # <function linear.<locals>.result at 0x7ff7b4148510>
print(type(ret))  # <class 'function'>
print(ret(5))     # 14
```

and the second one:

```
class linear:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a, self.b = a,b
   def __call__(self, x):
      return self.a * x + self.b

lin = linear(2, 4)
print(lin)             # <__main__.linear object at 0x7ff7b415a630>
print(type(lin))       # <class '__main__.linear'>
print(lin(5))          # 14
print(lin.__call__(5)) # 14 (this does exactly the same as the line above)
```

does that help clear things up or do you have a concrete question to one of the code lines here?

Comment: Thanks mahn. The last part of your solution (the last code) is what i was missing.